# Duplicate line according to 1 column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9D5R.png)

I would like to dupplicate each line the number of times indicated in the column "nombreIndividus".
I tried with `rep()` and `each =` and/or `time =` but I can't do it.

Example :

```
incomeGlobalCopie <- incomeGlobalCopie[rep(1:nrow(incomeGlobalCopie),
                                           each=incomeGlobalCopie$nombreIndividus)]
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Try `incomeGlobalCopie[rep(seq_len(dim(incomeGlobalCopie)[1]), incomeGlobalCopie[, "nombreIndividus"]), ]`

Comment: Hi Markus,  Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. Thanks, thanks, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Completely unelegant, but it does the trick:

```
names <- c("lion","tiger","flamengo")
replication <- c(4,5,3)
species <- data.frame(names, replication)
speciesCopy <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=0))
for(i in 1:length(species$names)){
  for(j in 1:species$replication[i]){
     speciesCopy <- rbind(speciesCopy, species[i,])
  }
}
speciesCopy
```

Comment: Hi CIAndrews,  Thanks for your answer but I search a solution without loop because the dataframe is big (1160000 rows) and after duplication it will be 5800000 rows.  I'm afraid that with a loop it's too long.  I will try and I will tell you.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi CIAndrews,  actually, it works really well, but it's a bit long on a big dataframe.  Thank a lot.